# ViewController in UINavigationController not filling view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I have not found how to make my view fill the available space as the root view controller (or pushed view controller) in a `UINavigationController`. I am attempting to use AutoLayout here, but I doubt that's the issue. In my app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And in my `ViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UILabel *companyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    companyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    companyLabel.text = @"We Build It";
    companyLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:companyLabel];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(companyLabel);

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[companyLabel]" options:0 metrics:@{} views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[companyLabel]" options:0 metrics:@{} views:views]];
}
```

And the label is centered in the screen instead of bound to the upper left because, I believe, that the view is just centered in the screen instead of filling the available space.

Comment: So is your question about the view controller filling up the view or about the layout of the label?

Comment: I "think" they are related. I want the label to be in the upper left, but it seems no matter what I do, everything is always centered. So if the view it lives in were to be the size of the available space on screen, then the label would be properly positioned.

Comment: Any reason why you need to call this line `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`?

Comment: So autolayout will work. Otherwise nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: I think you can remove that line self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints. Also for the label you need to set the height and width constraint, along with preferredMaxLayoutWidth if you want to restrict the max width of the label.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to remove the following line:

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

This will let the view controller view to have its full width and height according to the default autoresizing masks it has. This is what I get (I set the background color of the view to be green):

[image]

If the line above is still added, this is what I get (which seems to imply the view is not found anywhere since there is no trace of green color):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the exact behaviour I had and the desired behaviour I wanted.